# Proper Testing Methodology

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, testing

I've got a bit of an issue. I'm writing and continually developing an ASP.NET MVC application. The problem is, everytime I update one small part of our site (not even anything to do with our database), it seems to break about 4 other things in other parts of the site. I've been doing my best to anticipate it, but in the end, I know there are better ways out there to test, and I'm just wondering what the general consensus is for best practices?

Thanks!

Comment: You should locate the problem before looking for a solution. Is it a matter of bad code or bad tests?

Comment: At the moment it's an issue of not having any sort of proper testing structure in place.

Answer (score 0):

In short - not organized answer!

```
Have a plan.
Know what the change is.
Document what you are going to test and why.
Maintain a test suite (Regression) to execute after all major changes.
Keep improving your test cases and adding the ones you missed 
(there should be a test case associated with all your bugs. 
This will ensure the same bug doesn't get introduced due to regression.
```

And like you said have a proper structure, ensure process implementation, have better code reviews (catch the bugs before they get submitted) and keep reading a lot about all this.

This answer is open for editing to make it better.

Comment: Whats with the font coloring? :\